# Is there a mathematical term of an range where the start=end?

Tags: terminology

If I was asking someone to define a range of numbers and they put the same number for the starting point as the ending point.  Is there a mathematical term for this?

For example, a range of 1 to 1.  (Essentially, just 1).

Comment: Yes, it is a point

Comment: Also the closed interval $[1,1]$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An interval $[a,a]$ is called a *degenerate* interval. See

- http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Interval.html
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_(mathematics)#Terminology

Answer (score 1):

It is a point, or more specifically a collection of numbers with only 1 element.  Some ways to think about this is:

What does a number in the range $[a,a]$ look like?  Well, it is a number $\geq a$ and $\leq a$, and the only number like that is $a$ itself